# How to find identical lines from the following list

Tags: regex, sed, grep

```
 id="9IQo3oW38p4"
 id="1Ly3_5YdbOA"
 id="peH5Yw7R66Q"
 id="pjGL5ZJ878w"
 id="OjEKoXBZf7w"
```

We have several such id's in a certain file and some of them are identical and we would like to list all identical rows somehow. How should we do this?

Comment: Could there be spaces around equal sign?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
cat yourFileWithTheLines | sort | uniq -d
```

shorter version:

```
sort -u yourFileWithTheLines
```

Thanks @pooh for figuring that out to me ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You should man uniq

```
sort file | uniq -d
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can load it into an SQLite table with an index.

```
./sqlite3 my_database.db
> CREATE TABLE lines(line TEXT);
> CREATE INDEX i_line ON lines (line ASC);
> -- @ is not in our file
> .separator @
> .import '/home/me/my_file.txt' lines
> .output '/home/me/my_duplicates.txt'
> SELECT line FROM lines GROUP BY line HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
> .q
```

This way you still have your database and your index, querying it a second time for another thing could be more efficient than parseing it again with sort+uniq.